# Use already existing KMS key in Lambda functions that are managed through SAM/CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, amazon-kms

The situation is:
A lambda function is created using a SAM/CloudFormation. A policy is attached to allow this function to access an existing bucket (in the same region). This looks somehow like this:

```
  MyFunction:

    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
    .....
    Policies:
        - Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "s3:ListBucket"
              - "s3:PutObject"
              - "s3:GetObject"

            Resource: 
              - "arn:aws:s3:::my-great-existing-bucket"
              - "arn:aws:s3:::my-great-existing-bucket/*"
```

This means: Without modifying the policy of the existing bucket, the newly created lambda-function will now have access to that bucket.

But in this case this already existing bucket is additionally encrypted with an existing customer managed KMS key (again in the same region) so access will still be denied to the Lambda function. 
The goal would be to add the policy to use that existing key also directly to cloud-formation template. 
I found this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/iam-policies.html

My interpretation would be, that the named goal would usually be achieved only the other way round:
You need to modify the policy of the KMS-key. But they Key is of course not managed via the Cloud Formation Stack and therefore not manageable here (or am I wrong about that?).

So the only way to achieve it would be to activate general IAM Policies for the KMS-key?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam

Is that understanding correct?

Comment: The policy is incorrect. Can you please explain what do you want to achieve with your policy?

Comment: The policy should allow a new lambda function to read data from an existing bucket that is encrypted with an existing KMS-key

Comment: Lambda, KMS and bucket are in same account and region?

Comment: The KMS key, is customer managed or AWS managed?

Comment: @Marcin It is a customer managed key and everything is in the same region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the only way to achieve it would be to activate general IAM Policies for the KMS-key?

Yes. **That's correct**. If your customer managed KMS key does not have it, you have to modify KMS policy to allow lambda role. If you activate general IAM Policies, then you can just modify the lambda execution role with permissions to the KMS key.

Comment: Sorry, I did indeed copy paste the wrong version of the policy and forgot the second list element: `- "arn:aws:s3:::my-great-existing-bucket/*"`. Since this was not a crucial part of the actual question I updated with that line to avoid confusion.

Comment: To avoid confusion: maybe you could edit out the upper part of your answer since I fixed that and it was not a core part of the question?

Comment: Would there be some workaround to again restrict access to the KMS key then? In the end I would somehow like to achieve that only cloud formations templates executed by a certain user-account are allowed to use the KMS key. I guess the only way would be to predefine a dedicated role for those functions created by CloudFormation and then hardcode the role into the CloudFormation template. But this again will hinder CloudFormation to create dynamic roles for the functions

Comment: @and0r If you want to manage this by cloudformation, why not [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) the KMS key to it?

Comment: Would this allow some kind of "light" managing of that KMS-resource from a CF stack perspective? In setting the deletion policy to "Retain" this would at least ensure that the KMS-resource won't be deleted when the stack is removed. But I guess that other developers wouldn't be able to change the KMS-resource (e.g. add their own policies for their deployments) without messing up my CF-stack, would they? Or is there really a way to do an independent "append" of entries to "Sid": "Allow use of the key" (without knowing the rest of the policy/entries) using Cloudformation?

Comment: @and0r If you import it, it should be managed only using CFN, as you end up with a drift. The only other alternative is to create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html), and modify KMS policies using the resource.

Comment: Well, I guess all options are exhausted and described by now. I was stumbling over custom resources when writing the previous comment, but the characters ran out so I didn't want to bring it up (also because I have no idea how to do it properly). I will stick with the manual KMS-administration approach for now. It should be fine to manage it for <10 functions needing bucket access.